# Test for existence of an AD object in PowerShell using only Microsoft-provided cmdlets

Tags: active-directory, scripting, powershell

I want to test for the existence of a computer account in Active Directory with PowerShell using only tools from Microsoft.

Using Quest AD cmdlets, I can do this:

```
if (!(get-qadcomputer $name)){ Stuff }
```

That doesn't work with `get-adobject` or `get-adcomputer` as far as I can tell.

Is  there something simple that I'm missing? I've seen a couple hacky-looking solutions that trap all exceptions that get thrown, but that seems like it could give some false positives under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adpowershell/archive/2009/05/05/how-to-create-a-function-to-validate-the-existence-of-an-ad-object-test-xadobject.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
$c = Get-ADComputer <$ComputerName>
if($c -eq $null) { ItDoesntExist } else { ItLives }
```

This should do exactly what you need... you said it isn't working for you, why exactly?

---

Sorry, looks like this cmdlet actually throws an exception instead of simply returning `$null`, as documented [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/02/04/inventorying-computers-with-ad-powershell.aspx)... and it also ignores the `-erroraction` parameter (scroll down to the comments on the linked page).

Suggested workaround:

```
$errorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

Get-ADComputer <$ComputerName>
```

Or, better, see my other answer.

Comment: I get `Get-ADComputer : Cannot find an object with identity: 'test' under: 'DC=my,DC=domain'.
At line:1 char:20
+ $c = Get-ADComputer <<<<  "test"
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (test:ADComputer) [Get-ADComputer], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: 'test' under: 'DC=my,DC=domain'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Ma 
   nagement.Commands.GetADComputer` when running it against a machine that doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe do something with `-erroraction`?  Suppress the error and test for it?

Comment: Ops. Looks like it's a known (and frustrating) issue: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/02/04/inventorying-computers-with-ad-powershell.aspx (scroll down to the comments).

Comment: Yeah, not returning $null like a good cmdlet is what's been killing me. I'm trying out your other answer now, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete it and read the return code for that?

(Just kidding. Kind of.)

Answer (score 0):

To test an AD Object in general by DistinguishedName, you can use the following:

`[bool](Get-ADObject -Filter {DistinguishedName-eq "CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local"})`

Or, when you want to search by another property like samaccountname:

`[bool](Get-ADObject -Filter {sAMAccountname -eq "Administrator"})`

Both will return only a boolean ($true or $false) and can be used in conditional logic (if/else, etc).

Comment: Would this work with Get-ADComputer?

Comment: This works with a lot of cmdlets which return an object or not. If it returns an object (or more) and you cast it to type boolean it will become a true, without an object returned it will become a false.

Answer (score 0):

```
$errored=$false
try { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $SomeGroupName $SomeComputer  }
catch {
    $errored=$true
    Write-Output "$SomeComputer does not exist in AD,$_" | Tee-Object $errorLogFileName -Append
}
if ( $errored == $false) { 
    #either accept the computer is added to $SomeGroupName or delete it back out now that you know $someComputer exists
}
```